# Mongo pull object from array inside array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have inside my  mongoDB collection this document

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b633025579fac22e74bf3be"), 
"FLAGS" : [
    {
        "toSent" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b633025579fac22e74bf3c2"), 
                "phone" : "+84404040404"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b633025579fac22e74bf3c1"), 
                "phone" : "+212652253403"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b633025579fac22e74bf3c0"), 
                "phone" : "+212123456788"
            }
        ], 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b633025579fac22e74bf3bf"), 
        "action" : "group_p_a"
    }, 
    {
        "toSent" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b633031579fac22e74bf3c9"), 
                "phone" : "+212651077199"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b633031579fac22e74bf3c8"), 
                "phone" : "+84404040404"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b633031579fac22e74bf3c7"), 
                "phone" : "+212652253403"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b633031579fac22e74bf3c6"), 
                "phone" : "+212123456788"
            }
        ], 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b633031579fac22e74bf3c5"), 
        "action" : "group_p_a"
    }
], 
"time" : ISODate("2018-08-02T16:24:05.747+0000"), 
"action_user_phone" : "+212123456788", 
"idGroup" : "e534379a-1580-4568-b5ec-6eaf981538d2", 
"nomGroup" : "MOH FOR EVER", 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
```

}
**TODO**
I need to remove for example this element { "_id" : ObjectId("5b633025579fac22e74bf3c2"), "phone" : "+84404040404"}

**WHAT I DID**

```
GroupEvents.update({}, {$pull:{FLAGS:{$elemMatch:{toSent:{phone: "+84404040404"}  }}}},function(err,ret){
    if(err)
        console.log("error"+err);
    if(ret)
        console.log(ret);
});
```

It remove all what's inside toSent event if it doesn't match.

Any help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`$` `positional`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator instead of `$elemMatch` here

```
GroupEvents.update(
  { "Flags.toSent.phone": "+84404040404" },
  { "$pull": { "FLAGS.$.toSent": { "phone": "+84404040404" }}},
)
```

If you want remove from every element of `FLAGS` array this you need to use [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) the all positional operator

```
GroupEvents.update(
  { "Flags.toSent.phone": "+84404040404" },
  { "$pull": { "FLAGS.$[].toSent": { "phone": "+84404040404" }}},
)
```

Comment: it pull out only the first element for each array not all matched element, even if i use {multi:true}

Comment: what is your mongodb version... Updated the answer as well

Comment: my mongo versions is 3.4.2, i tried this, they said { [MongoError: cannot use the part (FLAGS of FLAGS.$[].toSent) to traverse the element ({FLAGS: [ { _id: ObjectId('5b633025579fac22e74bf3bf'),

Comment: You need to upgrade your mongodb version to 3.6 or 4.0 to use this